# Write text on new line (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have code where I write text to email body

Here is it

```
 string Body = _objModelMail.Body = "Ваши данные для входа это ваш Email"+ " \n Ваш пароль" + "  " + pass;
```

I try to write this on new line

> " \n Ваш пароль"

But email coming with all one line.

What I doin wrong?

Comment: use html formatting for the body of your email then use <br/> at where you want the line broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email use html format, So Try `<br/>` rather than `\n`.

Example:

```
string Body = _objModelMail.Body = "Ваши данные для входа это ваш Email"+ " <br/> Ваш пароль" + "  " + pass;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your email use html format, please use `<br />` for create newline

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<br />` [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) to produce a new line.

Also, use [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of string concatenation:

```
string Body = _objModelMail.Body = string.Format("Ваши данные для входа это ваш Email<br/>Ваш пароль {0}", pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change \n with html <br> tag or you can use StringBuilder class

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Body text here");
sb.AppendLine("New line start here ");
string body=sb.ToString();
```

or You can also create html formatted body , in this approach you can create any kind of email body , color formatting anything

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<table>");
sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>");
sb.AppendLine("Body text here");
sb.AppendLine("</tr></td>");
sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>");
sb.AppendLine("New line start here ");
sb.AppendLine("</tr></td>");
sb.AppendLine("</table>");
string body=sb.ToString();
```